# Can I make a USB Thumb Drive inserted in one port readable from another port?

Tags: usb

I want to setup a Raspberry PI so that a thumb drive at say `/dev/sdb1/` will also show up at `/dev/sdb2` so that a male-male USB cable can then be plugged into `dev/sdb2/` and then into my car stereo USB to be read as a USB drive.

Put another way, I want my cars USB slot to be able to be plugged into USB2 and read USB1(thumbdrive)

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to plug the thumbdrive straight into the car stereo?

Comment: @roamia - haha, it would of course, but I was thinking of doing something where when my PI starts up, it connects to the house wifi and rsyncs my latest music to itself.

Comment: So have your Pi look for a USB device being plugged in, and if it's got (say) a volume label called "Music" then rsync and umount/eject. You can plug the thumbstick in for an automatic update, and then just take it to the car for use.

Answer (score 1):

Provided I got clear what you're trying to achieve, this may have been (partially) answered there :

- [Can I make a USB port on my Linux computer look like a mass storage device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106110/can-i-make-a-usb-port-on-my-linux-computer-look-like-a-mass-storage-device)
- [Make a computer act as a virtual USB device for other equipments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120368/make-a-computer-act-as-a-virtual-usb-device-for-other-equipments)

It might be possible to do what you want, depending on your hardware + software + how much you're ready to hack both.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the RasPi's USB host adapter to not only run in device mode (which *can* be done, [according to this question at RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/71613/93995) but *both* in device mode (for the car stereo) *and* host adapter mode (for the actual USB drive) *simultaneously*. I'm not sure if the hardware can do that